# Number format in GWT - Round off issue

Tags: extjs, gwt

How to format a number without rounding off in GWT.

e.g. how would i get a double value from 23.49 after formatting as 23.4 not 23.5 , I looked at the definition of format() in NumberFormat - gwt-user.jar and it calls 
roundValue() which forces it to round. Is there a way to achieve this in GWT.

Answer (score 1):

You can call NumberFormat.format with two decimal places and then truncate the resulting String.

Comment: Thanks Andrei, That can surely be done  but isn't there anything available which could directly be used ?

Comment: this would roundoff the given value, 23.49 would become 23.5 as format method defaults calls the roundValue method. I tested this out already. Thanks

Comment: Good to know. Then you have to use my original suggestion.